# WSO2 Governance Registry fails to deploy uploaded CAR

Tags: wso2

I created a simple CAR project that contains Proxy Service, WSDL and 2 XSDs. Proxy Service is marked with EnterpriseServiceBus server role, while WSDL and XSDs - with GovernanceRegistry role.

I am able to upload this CAR to ESB and it deploys Proxy Service as expected.
However when I try to upload the same CAR to a standalone GReg, it shows "Succesfully uploaded CAR" message but does not deploy any of the artifacts. I have the following path configured for my artifacts in artifact.xml: "/_system/governance/services/cqproxy".

Please let me know what I am missing.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default configuration in Governance Registry (G-Reg) has a WSDL handler that deploys all WSDL files into /_system/governance/trunk/wsdls/..... Pls check if your WSDL is deployed into this location.

To deploy the WSDL in the registry path defined in your artifact.xml you will need to disable the handler function. This can be done in repository/conf/registry.xml file of your G-Reg distribution. Comment out the WSDL handler section that commences with

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Gillian

Comment: GReg did not deploy my artifacts under its default location neither. However, after commenting out WSDL and XSD handlers per your recommendation - GReg deployed all artifacts. The only problem I've noticed so far is that it did not create any dependencies between artifacts. How can this be fixed?

Comment: It also did not generate Service from my WSDL.

Comment: By default G-Reg is configured to deploy artifacts such as WSDLs in the registry path defined within the handler. Commenting out the handler as previously suggested is just a work around to deploy the WSDL in the specified location. However if your requirement is to deploy the WSDL in a user defined registry path as well as deploy the dependencies in G-Reg, this would require an extension of the handler through customizations. However just to give you a heads up there are limitations on the support package offerings for such customizations.

Comment: Got it. In this case why GReg did not deploy my WSDL and XSDs into default path ignoring my configuration before I commented out the handlers?

Comment: When creating the WSDL resource in the CAR file did you create it as follows? Create a registry resources project and then create a WSDL file registry resource within that project. Then create the resulting CApp and CAR file to be deployed in G-Reg. If you followed these steps the WSDL will be successfully uploaded and will be listed in WSDL list in the G-Reg management console and the dependencies are also available. I just tried it and it worked for me. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: That is exactly how I created my CAR. It contains a WSDL file + XSD used by the WSDL + another XSD referenced by the first XSD.

Comment: OK. I changed Registry paths for my WSDL and 2 dependent XSDs to match WSO2 default: /_system/governance/trunk/wsdls/... and /_system/governance/trunk/schemas/... and generated a CAR file. However, on upload Greg still displays "Could not evaluate WSDL Definition..." and "Could not read the XML Schema Definition file" in the system log. Does this mean that Governance Registry can't perform the basic form of governance which is dependency analysis?

Comment: Hi Alex, In order to help you solve your problem can you please try this as well. Create a GAR (Governance Archive) file and then upload this to G-Reg. Try this out and verify if you still encounter the same problem.

Comment: Gillian, yes I already tried GAR and it works for WSDLs and XSDs. However, my GReg CAR contains other resources such as XSLs, TXTs, etc which can't be deployed using GAR format. The last thing I want to do is to require 20 developers split GRreg project into 2 deliverables: GAR and CAR. Is there any way to get this done with CAR alone?

Comment: What you can do is, upload the created GAR as a registry resource to Dev Studio. You can then pack this into your CAR file and then deploy in G-Reg. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This approach works but it is quite dirty since developers will have to make several extra steps to get around this issue. I created a JIRA issue so WSO2 team can fix this: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-1691. Thanks for your assistance Gillian!

Comment: Actually I just tried to undeploy this CAR with embedded GAR but it failed with the following error: "ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.persistence.CarbonAppPersistenceManager} -  Error while removing registry resources of the artifact : eADS_2.gar". Apparently, even this approach has not been implemented end-to-end.

Comment: Also, CAR with embedded GAR is not recognized by ESB with embedded Registry. Thus the same CAR can't be deployed across different Carbon products.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for creating the JIRA. Will look into this improvement with the relevant product team.

Comment: Just to clarify further, GAR works only for G-Reg and does not work for the embedded registry.

Comment: Yes, we figured that :) Basically this issue breaks your universal CAR deployment across all Carbon products design.